# window() function exclude the date sent as end argument, any work around?

Tags: r, time-series, subset, xts, zoo

I want to use window function to subset a time series. However, the function excludes the date I input as end argument.

```
window(ts1, end = "2018-09-24")
```

I couldn't find any argument to change this behavior. Any thought?

Comment: can you pick "2018-09-25" instead?

Comment: end always includes the date you specified (if it is in the data). But without a reproducible example it is difficult to say what is going on. So add your code on how you got to ts1 and a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arose because of comparing two different types of data, Date and POSIXct.

I solved the issue by finding the indexes of the rows that are after that date and then excluded them from the dataset:

```
evaluation_date <- "2018-09-24"
indexes_removed <- which(as.numeric(as.Date(index(ts1))) > as.numeric(as.Date(evaluation_date)))
ts1 <- ts1[[-indexes_removed]
```